# Checkbox ordered based on Priority android

Tags: php, android, drag-and-drop

I download `JSON` from my database to create checkboxes dynamically.

How can I make it so that if the user drags a checkbox (when finger on an image) that the position of this checkbox wil be stored so that when I recreate the checkboxes again, the checkboxes will load in the same way the user dragged them to be in.

I use Id's to loop through the amount of checkboxes to be created.

---

> I do not ask for any code or whatsoever that does this for me. I just
>   want to know how to do this, and a push in the right direction.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want to achieve. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain ArrayList for Ids what you have created. When user dragged the list first remove the id from old position and add in with new position, then assign the arraylist to your adapter. then call notifydatasetchanged.

I think this will help you some what

Comment: My id's are created automatically in DB will this work if i adjust it? or should i create a totally new row?

Comment: you have to delete old row and insert new one